# Access Tokens for a public, non authorized user

Tags: laravel, authorization, jwt, token, laravel-passport

So I'm building an app for my company (yes I'm still new so please don't rip on me) and the idea of the app is that when anyone who visits a landing page and signs up for a seminar, that information will be saved into our database.  The thing is we are using the clients normal site and will do an ajax call to my built API.  My boss told me to use passport for authentication but I cannot wrap my head around this.  If it is a public endpoint and one does not have to be logged in or authorized to hit the API, why do I need passport?  If I do need passport how can I issue a token for the person who hit the webpage to sign up, if they don't have a log in and are not "authorized" . Sorry if this question does not make sense, this whole project doesn't make sense when we could just build them a new front end instead of using old antiquated technology.  I'm using laravel for the back end.

Comment: Access tokens don't really make a lot of sense to me, if you're not going to require your users to actually authenticate themselves (which is the whole point of Passport). If you're going to require them to actually register themselves in the process of enrolling for the seminar, it makes sense though.

Comment: That's just it we are saving their information in our DB for email/lead purposes but other than that we are not giving them a login or anything like that.  Just a basic confirmation email saying hey you've signed up for this seminar.  So to me it doesn't really seem like tokens/passport is needed.  I've created a few gate definitions for user authentication already for the "admin" side so I don't think I even need passport.

Comment: In that case I don't think you need any authentication, you might want to look at some spam prevention though.

Comment: I faced a similar situation among two different Laravel apps I build, in which one of them calls a webhook on the other. I do allow guest users, but I think that what you actually want here is to make sure that your webhook on Laravel is triggered by a trusted source (your client's landing) and not another one. You may use passport, but you don't necessarily need it for this. What you can do is to use a *token* shared among both apps to make sure your webhook is triggered only by a trusted source.